# Change codec format of video which is captutred using openRTSP live555

Tags: codec, live555

I want to capture video on server using `openRTSP.exe` from `live555` code and access it from server.
I'm able to capture the video but it is in `h264` codec format. Can we change  this codec format other than `h264` like `wma` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a codec library, such as FFMPEG, to transcode (decode then re-encode) the data to the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

**openRTSP.exe** has no control over the codec format of data. Whatever server is sending will be received on the client. if you want to receive data in other format, you have to **change in the server side**. and by the way Live555 is just used for media communication over network using **RTSP**. there is no Encoding or decoding.